# SQL - display only max # of type by type name for different categories

Tags: sql-server

My first query:

```
`SELECT M.type, U.campaign_id, count(*) as NumEvents 
 FROM dbo.Events E 
 JOIN dbo.Meals M
 ON E.meal_id = M.meal_id 
 JOIN dbo.Users U
 ON U.userid = E.userid
 GROUP BY M.type, U.campaign_id
 ORDER BY M.type`
```

That gives me this result:

```
TYPE         Campaign-id       # of Events
Chinese        FB                2
Chinese        RE                1
Chinese        TW                2
French         FB                1
French         PI                2
French         RE                2
Italian        FB                3
Italian        RE                2
Italian        TW                2
Mexican        RE                1
```

Where Type is the genre of the meal, Campaign_id refers to the type of person who ate the meal, and # of events refers to how many times a person with a certain Campaign_id ate the certain genre of meal.

I need a SQL Server query that will give me the Campaign_id that is associated with the most events for each meal type. Thanks

The result should look like this:

```
TYPE         Campaign-id with Greatest Number of events
Chinese               FB or TW                
French                RE or PI              
Italian               FB                
Mexican               RE
```

Comment: Let's start by posting your query as a code, not a picture.

Comment: Images are a *horrible* way to post SQL text.

Comment: @Tina [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40118902/edit) with formatted query and place it within code tags.

Comment: Please do not show your code as a picture. Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time doing this. I will make sure to enter code next time in code boxes. Thanks for the instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, simplify your existing query:

```
SELECT m.type, U.campaign_id, count(*) as NumEvents
FROM dbo.Events E JOIN
     dbo.Meals M
     ON E.meal_id = M.meal_id JOIN
     dbo.Users U
     ON U.userid = E.userid
GROUP BY m.type, U.campaign_id;
```

Then, let's fix this to get what you want:

```
SELECT mc.*
FROM (SELECT m.type, U.campaign_id, count(*) as NumEvents,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.type ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Events E JOIN
           dbo.Meals M
           ON E.meal_id = M.meal_id JOIN
           dbo.Users U
           ON U.userid = E.userid
      GROUP BY m.type, U.campaign_id
     ) mc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon - Thanks so much - this is a great start. It looks like it is counting the campaign_id regardless of the meal type. I need it to show me which campaign_id shows up the most for each meal type.

Comment: @Tina . . . I confused users and types.  The current query should do what you want.